# Is there a way to check if a user has specific rights?

Tags: .net, windows, security, rights

In my application I'm using *ntrights.exe*, that is part of [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displayLang=en), to grant and revoke a specific user right.

For example to grant a user "Log on as a server" right, I execute using shell object following command:

```
ntrights -u User +r SeServiceLogonRight
```

However *ntrights* doesn't allow you to check if a user has a specific right.

Can you tell me how I can check if a user has a specific right?

**Update**
The question is posted here because it's part of .NET application I'm writing.  If any one knows, how to do it using code, please post it here.

Comment: Is this part of a program you're writing?  If not, it should go to Super User.

Comment: IMHO it belongs in serverfault.

Comment: It's part of .NET application.  I would appreciate if anyone can show me how do it in .NET code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [LsaEnumerateAccountRights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaenumerateaccountrights) ([see also](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316110115/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132958)).

I don't know if .NET provides a wrapper class, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need LsaEnumerateAccountRights().  That isn't exposed in .NET but is being used.  Use Reflector and take a look at the private ServiceProcessInstaller.AccountHasRight method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an Active Directory domain, you can administer this through `System.DirectoryServices`.

[System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706021%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Other things you might look up are `ADSI` and `LDAP`.